Protecting sill beams on 140-year-old house
I'm residing my 1880's house and am contemplating how I'm going to deal with the sill beams. They're quite thick, with some dry rot due to exposure and pests.
Having dealt with termites when I bought the house 15 years ago, I'm interested in making the tasty parts of my house as difficult to get to as possible, so it seems stupid not to do something with the beams while I've got them exposed.
At this point, I plan on facing the foundation wall below the beams with Rockwool Comfortboard, faced with cement board, dug in 18" or so. It won't deter termites, but it's not attractive to them, either.
At the sill beam, I'm contemplating a copper bug screen flashing, but I'd like to provide additional protection for the sill beam.
I see liquid rubber or other elastomeric coatings which seem like a good idea, though they require re-coating in deck applications. Not sure that matters here where there's no UV exposure and minimal exposure to water, however.
I'm open to using borate-treated products, too, but it seems impossible to source lumber that's pre-treated. I would likely want to use 1x6" pine as an outer sheathing over the sill beam, if I were to use it. I suppose I can probably just bathe regular boards in a borate solution to get that done...
Any thoughts?

You will never block access adequately to keep insects out. That's a fools game. It only takes one tiny opening to collapse your house of copper. Instead, make the wood less tasty with liquid treatments, granules, etc.

For the record, I referenced copper flashing once - and it will be a 6” strip, if I elect to use it at all.  Not sure where the “copper house” comes from in that.  Regardless, the bulk of my question is focused on multiple other mitigation techniques and I’m curious about best practices regarding them.
